# Why can't mollie call webhook URL?

Tags: webhooks, mollie

I have build a custom webshop using PHP and typescript with React, and to process payments I am using Mollie.

I have tested everything locally and on the server (shared webhosting) and it all works. But when I make a payment in either live or test mode Mollie prompts that it failed to call the webhook. This is what I see in my dashboard:

> Failed to call webhook (Got HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed instead of 20x)

I tried to call the webhook from Postman and a simple HTML form:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://shop.example.com/webhooks/webhook.php">
    PaymentID: <input type='text' name='id'/>
    <input type='submit' value='send'/>
</form>
```

From both Postman and the HTML form I get a positive response `200 OK`, also the payment gets processed correctly. I know this because the database gets updated to verify the order and I get a confirmation email. Which are actions performed in the webhook script. So the script works correctly.

Sometimes I either see this message in chrome:

> ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT

I think that this issue is caused by the fact that I don't have a SSL certificate for my domain, but can't find anything about this online. Also the shop is hosted on a subdomain `shop.website.org/`.

Can anyone verify that this issue is caused by the lack of a SSL certificate or that something else might cause this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem!

Mollie requires a SSL certificate, it won't call your Webhook over http only https.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint about another reason, why the webhook URL may not seem to be called:
By default all POST requests in Laravel are protected with the Middleware VerifyCsrfToken. The webhook call is a POST request. But not from a form. So one has to define an exception. Open app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php. Add your webhook url to the protected $except array.